# Videos on html page hosted on firebase hosting are not working on Safari

Tags: html, video, safari, firebase-hosting

I uploaded the following HTML on firebase hosting:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <video controls preload="none"><source src="https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4" type="video/mp4" /></video>
    </body>
</html>
```

available at this address:
https://true-video.firebaseapp.com/test.html

works on Chrome but not on Safari: the video is not playing.
The same file works on my local with Safari.

Comment: which Safari? works fine for me on macOS 10.14.6, Safari 12.1.2 ... takes a couple of seconds for metadata to load (have you encoded with the MOOV atom at the front?) but plays fine. Do you get any errors (network or console) in Safari Dev Tools?

Comment: hi @Offbeatmammal I'm also on macOS 10.14.6, Safari 12.1.2. I didn't encoded the video myself it's just an external link. A you sure the video in this link is working for you ?!? https://true-video.firebaseapp.com/test.html

Comment: I press play button, and after about 2-3 seconds a 5s big buck bunny clip plays